# error in Assigning values to bytes in a 2d array of registers in Verilog .Error

Tags: warnings, hardware, verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

Hi  when i write this piece of code :

```
module memo(out1);

reg [3:0] mem [2:0]  ;

output wire [3:0] out1;


    initial
          begin
 mem[0][3:0]=4'b0000;

 mem[1][3:0]=4'b1000;

 mem[2][3:0]=4'b1010;
 end

 assign out1= mem[1];

endmodule
```

i get the following warnings which make the code unsynthesizable

WARNING:Xst:1780 - Signal **mem<2>** is never used or assigned. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal **mem<1>** is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 1000.
WARNING:Xst:1780 - Signal  **>** is never used or assigned. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.

Why am i getting these warnings ?
Haven't i assigned the values of mem[0] ,mem[1] and mem[2]!?? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you verified that an initial block is synthesizable, or that assigning an initial value to a register array is synthesizable? This is a pretty dangerous practice in my mind. Using a normal clocked process is much more portable.

Comment: hmmm that could be a problem. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your module has no inputs and a single output -- out1.  I'm not totally sure what the point of the module is with respect to your larger system, but you're basically initializing mem, but then only using mem[1].  You could equivalently have a module which just assigns out1 to the value 4'b1000 (mem never changes).  So yes -- you did initialize the array, but because you didn't *use* any of the other values the xilinx tools are optimizing your module during synthesis and "trimming the fat."  If you were to simulate this module (say in modelsim) you'd see your initializations just fine.  Based on your warnings though I'm not sure why you've come to the conclusion that your code is unsynthesizable. It appears to me that you could definitely synthesize it, but that it's just sort of a weird way to assign a single value to 4'b1000.

With regards to using initial begins to store values in block ram (e.g. to make a ROM) that's fine.  I've done that several times without issue.  A common use for this is to store coefficients in block ram, which are read out later.  That stated the way this module is written there's no way to read anything out of mem anyway.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This module doesnt do anything in my larger system. I was just trying to understand the working of verilog which will inturn affect how i design the larger part of my system. Thanks for the valuable feedback .

Comment: Just to clarify this really has nothing to do with verilog as much as it has to do with the xilinx tools optimizing your module.  As I mentioned a simulator would have shown you all the values of mem.  You could have done the same thing in vhdl or even in a schematic and gotten the same results.  It's not that different than a compiler getting rid of/warning you of unused variables in a sequential language (e.g. c).